# Can i use Honeywell android application in my android phone for testing purpose

Tags: android, honeywell

I am developing an app for my Honeywell CN80 device. But i don't have device right now. So can i debug android app in my mobile device to test application?

Or any other solution to debug application?

Comment: I'm developing for Honeywell barcode scanner CT50 and I use Visual Studio's Android Emulator as well as my own Nokia 3 with Android 8.0 to test the app. Make sure developer mode is enabled on your android device.

Comment: In general yes. But if you want to use sensor data then check if the device has that sensors.

Comment: @bigb055 Yes,developer mode is enabled on my device. I am using "Moto m" device to scan barcode.